# Restore backup solution for busy sites

Tags: nodes, backups

Today one of my users went and deleted the root of an Organic Group and wiped out all of the child nodes from that group and it's associated menu entries.

I have a backup, so I can restore, but in the time between I was informed of the problem and when it occured, other people were making updates to the site - so it wouldn't be as simple as just falling back to the last backup.

Happily, it was a simple group which is easily re-creatable - but I know one day, someone is going to delete a node which isn't trivial to re-create.

We've all had a colleage (or done it ourselves) who has called the local sysadmin and said "I accidentally deleted e-mail xxx - please restore it" - and the sysadmin goes and does it. My question is: How can I do this for a Drupal site? Ie. I want to be able to restore a node, or a set of nodes without completely rolling back.

Any ideas? Would love to hear from people with experience in dealing with this kind of problem. I can see there are modules such as "Feeds" and "Node Import" but I'm looking for peoples opinions on best solutions based on their experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One answer in this situation is never to permit deletions in the first place.  Use the publish flag or some other mechanism to remove the content from view, but retain it in the database.  An admin would be able to restore any content simply by 'publishing' it again.

Comment: Agree, if you have issues with content being deleted, then perhaps you should remove that permission from people who don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Override Node Options](http://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module to allow my users to unpublish content but I have removed their ability to delete most content types.